# extract distinct list of number from a list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a list of strings with the following values:

```
"/manufacturers/244/rz-xvxcv/images/swed"
"/manufacturers/23/rz-gf/images/sltn"
"/manufacturers/34/rz-dffdf/images/five"
"/manufacturers/23/rz-gfgf/images/lead"
"/manufacturers/322/rz-dfg/images/carr"
"/manufacturers/3789/rz-fgdfgfg/images/zing"
```

I need to extract a distinct list of the number values that fall in the pattern `/manufacturers/[int]/rz-`

So in the above example my new list would contain: 244,23,34,322,3789

Can this be done using RegEx and Linq?

Comment: See now, you will need a regex to do this. If they are all the same, just use `@"\d+"`.  If they are not, and need to be qualified, you will have to use `@"^/manufacturers/(\d+)/rz-"`. Those are the only two options. The worst thing you could do is to split on `/` which is useless.

Comment: @sln If the OP needs to verify that they start with "/manufacturers/" then they could just use `StartsWith` in a `Where`.  Still no need for a regular expression.  I don't see how splitting on `/` would be the worst thing.

Comment: @juharr - Split resilts in this context is being used positional to assume an array element is a number. Which still doesn't validate the sequence `/manufacturers/\d+/rz-`. You know maybe it could be validated after a split, but then why not just use a regex ?

Comment: @sln Again the OP can just add checking to make sure the second part of the path is numeric.  `paths.Where(p=>p.StartsWith("/manufacturers/")).Select(p=>p.Split('/')[2]).Where(d=>d.All(char.IsNumber)).Select(d=>int.Parse(d))`.  Now at this point it would be less code to use a regex, but not more performant, so it just depends on which is more important.

Comment: @juharr - Yeah, I guess. But I'd be willing to bet that `@"^/manufacturers/(\d+)/rz-"` is more efficient and easier to maintain. .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just use `Split` instead of regular expressions

```
var numbers = paths.Select(p=>int.Parse(p.Split('/')[2])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not super abstract or reusable, but very to-the-point.

```
var numbers = paths.Select(p => int.Parse(p.Substring(15, p.IndexOf('/', 15) - 15)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use RegEx and LINQ:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)");
var numbers = paths.Select(i => regex.Match(i).Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this patter
`(\d+)(?!.*\1)`
not extracted in order though
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/175)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  \d            # <digit 0-9>
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  .             # Any character except line break
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
  \1            # Back reference to group (1)
)               # End of Negative Look-Ahead
```